# SQLite3 with Flask Insert only allowing 1 character

Tags: sqlite, flask

I'm using Flask and trying to insert names (text) into an SQLite3 DB. The DB has one table (guests) and one column (name). However, it will only accept 1 character during the insert; anything more is failing.

If I hardcode 'nm' as a value, it still fails, so I don't think it's the Html template. I can manually add a value of varying length to the DB with the 'DB Browser' app, so I'm really at a loss here. Here's a code snippet.

```
    @app.route('/addrec', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def addrec():
        msg = "msg"
        if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                nm = request.form['nm']
    
                with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as con:
                    cur = con.cursor()
                    cur.execute('''Insert into guests values (?)''', nm)
                    con.commit()
                    msg = "Record successfully added"
```

Comment: Show the table definition for guests. From the SQLite3 REPL, `.schema guests` will print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second argument to `cur.execute` should be a tuple:

```
cur.execute('''Insert into guests values (?)''', (nm,))
```

Why?  If, for example, you call that argument `arg` then `arg[0]` is the string value you require (`nm`): the first item in that tuple.

Otherwise (when passing `nm` instead of the tuple) it will read `nm[0]` which is the first character of the string `nm`.

Comment: That's the answer. Thank you!